# Multidimensional indexing in Numpy with tuples as indices for certain axes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array which is really an array of matrices. I want to set the diagonals to zero by using the following approach. When I print the tuple and `din` it is exactly the same, but it returns different views of the array.

```py
m = np.random.normal(0, 0.2, (10, 4, 4))
din = np.diag_indices(m.shape[1], ndim = 2)

m[:, np.array([0,1,2,3]), np.array([0,1,2,3])]) # It returns an array of diagonals as expected
m[:, tuple(din)] # It returns the array
```

What did I miss here?

Comment: You need to unpack `din` like this `m[:, *din] `

Comment: I've already tried this, but it gives me `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Are you sure that it comes that line? You have an additional `)` after the last `]` in `m[:, np.array([0,1,2,3]), np.array([0,1,2,3])])`

Comment: Which python version do you have?

Comment: @Plagon Yes. The extra `)` is due to the fact I used `print` in my code to check the results and I didn't wanted to post it in the question.

Comment: @mozway `3.9.7 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Sep 29 2021, 19:20:46) 
[GCC 9.4.0]`

Comment: Then try `m[(slice(None), *din)]`, `m[:, *din] ` in only supported since python 3.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in comments, you need to unpack the indices.

Since python 3.11, you can use:

```
m[:, *din]
```

Output:

```
array([[ 8.61622699e-02, -1.46919069e-01, -9.37771599e-02,
         1.94698315e-03],
       [ 1.60933774e-01, -2.77077615e-02, -1.74135776e-01,
        -1.72223723e-01],
       [-1.54804225e-01,  1.08146714e-01,  2.51844877e-01,
        -2.91622737e-02],
       [ 1.22213756e-02,  1.59703456e-02, -1.41757563e-01,
        -5.02470362e-02],
       [ 1.49296012e-01, -9.60208199e-03, -4.82484338e-01,
         1.58012139e-02],
       [-3.09847219e-01, -1.13959996e-01, -6.71019475e-01,
         3.17810448e-01],
       [ 2.04860543e-04, -2.16311908e-01,  1.39098046e-01,
        -1.40102017e-01],
       [-5.82402679e-02,  2.55831587e-01, -3.74597159e-01,
         1.23205316e-01],
       [-1.23942861e-01,  1.40365188e-02, -2.16884333e-02,
        -2.08800511e-02],
       [ 1.02934324e-01, -1.81953630e-01,  2.35600757e-01,
        -2.29315601e-01]])
```

This syntax is however not supported in older python versions, in this case you can build a single tuple:

```
m[tuple((slice(None), *din))]

# or
m[(slice(None), *din)]
```